# Add data onto json/list (nested json) but getting error 'unhashable type: 'list'

Tags: python, json, list, api, tuples

I'm accessing devices and collect some info and save it as json and parse it to the db api via https. I have check some similar questions but still lost to find the correct answer.
I want to add data onto my json file and it give me an error below

```
  **temp[data["host_details"]] = temp_dict
 TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'**
```

line code below

```
data = {"local_hostname":"","local_ipaddress":"","host_details": []}
outfile = "list_hostname.csv"
for device in devices['list']:
           temp[data["local_hostname"]] = 
           connection.find_prompt().rstrip('>')
           temp[data["local_ipaddress"]] = device['ip']

           with open("list_hostdetails.csv") as host_file:
               hosts = host_file.readlines()
           temp_dict = {}
           for dd in hosts:
               temp_dict["device_Name"] = dd[1]
               data["host_details"].append(temp_dict)
               temp_dict = {}
           temp[data["host_details"]] = temp_dict       

           jsonFile["device"].append(temp)
```

Add data list onto device[]. I have troubleshootg this for few days...and still no luck...appreciate your assistance to guide me further. Thank you all.

Comment: The error message says it all. `data["host_details"]` is a list, and lists cannot be dictionary keys because they are not hashable.

Comment: Thank you sir...do u mean that cannot use data={}? Sorry...still learning to do it correctly...thanks

Comment: No, you can't do `temp[data["host_details"]]` because the key (i.e. `data["host_details"]`) is a list.

Comment: just for testing...I tried change my data list i.e. data = "local_hostname","local_ipaddress","host_details" and comment """ with open("list_hostdetails.csv") ... temp[data["host_details"]] = temp_dict """ and code can run and produce device_scanner.json file but no data about host_details...if I change back my data list {[]} and uncomment.... i will get the same hashable error...

Comment: I remove temp..see how it goes...

Comment: Remove temp resolve the problem...thanks to all